# How to create a inherited usercontrol from a mustinherit usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, user-controls, visual-studio-2015

I've created a class ctl_000 thats inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl using the IDE in VS 2015 "Create new Item >> Inherited User Control" Function.

Now I want to create another usercontrol ctl_001 that inherits from ctl_000. However, when I change the definition in ctl_000 to **MustInherit** I cannot select ctl_000 from the "Inheritance Picker" dialog.

How can I create an inherited usercontrol using the "Inheritance Picker" dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The designer provides the WYSIWYG view of a control by creating an instance of the base class at design time.  So the inherited properties can be displayed in the Properties window and you can change them and, optionally, their value have a visible effect in the designer.  Most easily seen for BackColor and Font, etcetera.

When you use MustInherit then that can no longer work, that makes the class abstract with no option to create an instance.  You must therefore omit the keyword to support designable inherited controls.

Channeling why you are trying to do this, presumably you really want to hide the base class from the toolbox.  Give it the `<ToolboxItem(False)>` attribute.

Comment: The intention is to create a set of controls that follows the same structure. I.e. a few properties and methods that all subcontrol should override.Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Well, that works just fine as well when you omit MustInherit.